# How to use ajax in wordpress and sending the data without refreshing ?

Tags: theme-development, ajax

I'm trying to populate a couple textareas with address from the customer name in a select field.

this is what I have for may select field

```
<select id="customers">
  <option value="None Selected"></option>
  <?PHP
    $customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM _cif_customers_table;");
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
      echo '<option value="'.$customer->id.'">'.$customer->company.'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

and I need the addresses to be in textareas like

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <fieldset style="text-align:left;padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);">
    <legend>Sold To</legend>
      <textarea style="resize:none;" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <fieldset style="text-align:left;padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);">
    <legend>Ship To</legend>
      <textarea style="resize:none;" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you .. +1 for this if you understand.

First step 
//yours dynamic dropdown field

```
    <select id="customers">
      <option value="None Selected"></option>
      <?PHP
        $customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM _cif_customers_table;");
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
          echo '<option value="'.$customer->id.'">'.$customer->company.'</option>';
        }
      ?>
    </select>
```

Second step :
//your customer data will show after fetch the data from customer table using ajax

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
          <fieldset style="text-align:left;padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);">
            <legend>Sold To</legend>
              <textarea id="text_area" style="resize:none;" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Third step :
//your ajax using on change function

```
<script>
        $('#customers').on('change', function() {

          //get the value
          var customer_id = $(this).val();
          /// run the ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',  //ajax url
                type: 'post',
                data: { action: 'customer_data', customer_id: customer_id },  // ajax parameters
                success: function(data) {

                       $('#text_area').html( data ); // fetch data show on textarea 

                }
            });

        }
        });
        </script>
```

//function.php ajax

```
add_action('wp_ajax_customer_data' , 'customer_data');  //ajax parameter action
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customer_data','customer_data');
        function customer_data(){
            $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id']; //id

            //fetch the customer data here .....Your QUERY
            //and return the values.
            die;
            }
```